# Codeigniter - Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting this error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::findVenueInfo()" when I try to use one of my models.

I have a view with this anchor:

```
echo anchor('welcome/searchVenue/' . $row->venue_id, $row->venue);
```

which generates a link like: http://localhost/ci-llmg/index.php/welcome/searchVenue/1

the method called is

```
function searchVenue()
{
    $this->load->model('venues');
    //get venue info
    $data['info'] = $this->venues->findVenueInfo($this->uri->segment(3)); //this line generates the error

}
```

and the findVenueInfo function in the model (venues.php) is:

```
function findVenueInfo($id)
{
    $data = array();
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $Q = $this->db->get('venues');
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($Q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    $Q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

..but the result of this is Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::findVenueInfo()
I'm probably missing something stupid, but can't get it to work! What do you think?

Comment: FIXED - i knew it was something stupid :)

the controller was using $this->db->findVenueInfo instead of $this->venue->findVenueInfo.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure your `index.php` file at the root of ur project have included bootstrap in proper place

Go to the end of the `index.php` file and include the bootstrap file just before including `codeigniter.php`.

Your `index.php` file should have its end lines look like this.

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *

 * And away we go...
 *
 */

require_once APPPATH.'third_party/datamapper/bootstrap.php';

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function findVenueInfo($id)
{
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select()->from('venues')->where('id', $id);<----change it to

    $Q = $this->db->get();<----change it to
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($Q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    $Q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: function findVenueInfo($id) { 

$data = array(); $this->db->select()->from('venues')->where('id', $id);<----change it to

$Q = $this->db->get();<----change it to
if ($Q->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach ($Q->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}

$Q->free_result();
return $data;

}

Comment: consider the first line which is not in grey background

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error and found that in 3.0 I needed to enable query_builder in application/config/database.php

```
$query_builder = TRUE;
```